# Can I force variadic template to take a specific type of argument

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates

In C++ templates there is a concept called explicit template argument specification, which means that I can force the compiler to create a template function of the given type. e.g.

```
template <class T1, class T2>

void foo(T1 t1prm, T2 t2prm) {
    /* function body */
}

foo<double, double>(1,2);
```

Can I do something similar with a variadic template function? I don't have a particular use case. Variadic templates are new to me and I am just trying to understand the capabilities of the new (well, to me) concept.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes.

```
template<typename... Args>
void f(const Args&... args)
{
}

int main()
{
   f<int>(1.0, 2, 3.0);
}
```

here will be called function `f<int, int, double>`.

You can check it like this

```
template<typename... Args>
void f(const Args&... args)
{
   using swallow = int[];
   (void)swallow{0, (std::cout << typeid(args).name() << std::endl, 0)...};
}
```